# material-ui creates many duplicated classes

Tags: material-ui, next.js, ssg

Is it possible to avoid the **duplication of class definitions** in a (server generated) page, styled with material-ui ?

In my Next.js / Material-UI app, I have a global `styles.ts` file, with e.g.:

```
export const styles = (theme) => createStyles({
    myButton: {
        '&:hover': { color: '#ff0' },
        '&.active': { color: '#f00' },
        fontSize: '1.23rem'
    }
});
```

After building, the generated page contains the one "copy" of this style definition for each component instance that uses this style, like:

```
<style id="jss-server-side">
    .myButton-1 { font-size: 1.23rem; }
    .myButton-1:hover { color: #ff0; }
    .myButton-1.active { color: #f00; }
    
    .myButton-2 { font-size: 1.23rem; }
    .myButton-2:hover { color: #ff0; }
    .myButton-2.active { color: #f00; }
    
    ...
</style>
```

I already tried this approach with the [jss-plugin-global](https://v4.mui.com/styles/advanced/#global-css), which removes the postfix numbers, but still inserts copies into the file, like:

```
// styles.ts
export const styles = (theme) => createStyles({
    '@global': {
        '.myButton': {
            '&:hover': { color: '#ff0' },
            '&.active': { color: '#f00' },
            fontSize: '1.23rem'
        }
    }
}
```

```
// output:
<style id="jss-server-side">
    .myButton { font-size: 1.23rem; }
    .myButton:hover { color: #ff0; }
    .myButton.active { color: #f00; }
    
    .myButton { font-size: 1.23rem; }
    .myButton:hover { color: #ff0; }
    .myButton.active { color: #f00; }
    
    ...
</style>
```